# Lock free single producer/single consumer circular buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, lock-free

I have been looking at a lock free single producer/single consumer circular buffer on [this website](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/43510/lock-free-single-producer-single-consumer-circular) when I couldn't figure out why a specific memory barrier was needed.
I have carefully read a hundread time [the standard rules about memory order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) but I don't understand what I'm missing.

With this implementation, there is only a unique thread which can call the `push()` function and another unique thread which can call the `pop()` function.

Here is the `Producer` code:

```
bool push(const Element& item)
{       
  const auto current_tail = _tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);  //(1)
  const auto next_tail = increment(current_tail);

  if(next_tail != _head.load(std::memory_order_acquire))            //(2)               
  {     
    _array[current_tail] = item;                                    //(3)
    _tail.store(next_tail, std::memory_order_release);              //(4)
    return true;
  }
  return false; // full queue
}
```

Here is the `Consumer` code:

```
bool pop(Element& item)
{
  const auto current_head = _head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);    //(1)
  if(current_head == _tail.load(std::memory_order_acquire))           //(2)
    return false; // empty queue

  item = _array[current_head];                                       //(3)
  _head.store(increment(current_head), std::memory_order_release);   //(4)
  return true;
}
```

I understand why the `Producer (4)` and the `Consumer (2)` statements are absolutly needed, this is because we have to make sure that all writes that *happened before* the `(4) released store` by the `Producer`will be visible side effects once the `consumer` will see the stored value.

I also understand why the `Consumer (4)` statement is needed, this is to make sure that the `Consumer (3)` load will be performed before the `Consumer (4)` store will be performed.

**The question**

- Why is the `Producer (2)` load needs to be performed with *acquire semantic* (instead of *relaxed*)? Is it to prevent `Producer (3) or (4)` to be reodered before the condition (at compile time or at runtime)?

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ done ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we need prove that

```
_array[current_tail] = item; // push(3)
```

excecuted **after** conforming (`current_head == current_tail`)

```
item = _array[current_head]; // pop(3)
```

is completed. we can overwrite cell, only after data from it already copied to item

the

```
_head.load(std::memory_order_acquire) // push(2)
```

synchronized with

```
_head.store(increment(current_head), std::memory_order_release);   //pop(4)
```

via Release-Acquire ordering:

all memory writes ( *pop(3)* ) that happened-before the atomic store-release ( *pop(4)* )  on `_head` become visible side-effects once the atomic load-acquire ( *push(2)* ) is completed on `_head`.

so Producer code after *push(2)* is completed, guaranteed to see result of *pop(3)*. this mean that data from `_array[current_head]` is copied to item and result of this operation is visible for Producer code after *push(2)*, so `_array[current_head]` already free.

from another side from `memory_order_acquire` load description - no reads or writes ( *push(3)* ) in the current thread can be reordered before this load. so *push(3)* will be execute already after *push(2)* load complete, but at this point *pop(3)* already completed

```
item = _array[current_head];                                        //pop(3)
_head.store(increment(current_head), std::memory_order_release);    //pop(4)
-----
    _head.load(std::memory_order_acquire);                          //push(2)
    _array[current_tail] = item;                                    //push(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.Something still bother me with the barrier *in* the condition of the `Producer` code. Because of possible speculative execution, the line `if(next_tail != _head.load(std::memory_order_acquire))` could be compiled as 
`const auto head = _head.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
//then here perform the stores
if(next_tail == head)
{
//restore he memory as it was
}`

as you can see, the condition has been reversed due to speculative store and it could harm the memory if the pop function were called.
To me the acquire barrier should be in the condition.

Comment: @Yoo - i not understand what you try say.  when we do load with `memory_order_acquire` - *no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load.*

Comment: I want to say that the `load-acquire` could be executed before the condition test, so the store could still be executed before the condition (but still after the barrier). Is it more clear ? It is not beceause you write `if(next_tail != _head.load(std::memory_order_acquire))` that it couldn't be interpreted as first a load then the condition

Comment: @Yoo - no. you wrong. the `_head.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` will be executed *before* `_array[current_tail] = item; `

Comment: @Yoo in which order will be 2 loads from memory - `_head.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` and `next_tail` - no play role, because `next_tail` local, private to thread variable. but store to memory `_array[current_tail] = item` can not begin until load acquire full completed

Comment: @Yoo - and by your "logic" possible say the next : `if (p != 0) *p = x;` - cpu before test are p != 0 execute speculative `*p=x` ? in this case programming at all impossible. sense on acquire-load memory order exactly - no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load.  and **depended** by condition store can not be executed before condition check. this break all logic. if this will be **independed** (from any condition) store - yes, cpu can reorder it if no acquire barrier. but here exist acquire semantic and store **conditional**

Comment: @Yoo - i be say next - the *push(3)* in any case will be execute after *push(2)* even if not use any memory barriers - because the  *push(3)* is depend from *push(2)* result. but we need here also not reorder *pop(3)* and *pop(4)* - the execution must be strict in this order - we can not increment _head before complete pop/copy data from cell. for this is and need use `memory_order_release` in *pop(4)* but from c++ view unpaired `memory_order_release` have no sense. must be coresponding load from same var with `memory_order_acquire`

Comment: @RbBm I have edited the question to make sure that what I want to say is clear :)

Comment: @Yoo -i think you need ask absolute another question - *store due to speculative execution* - are possible such store at all. are possible speculative execution which have *side effect*. now your current question only obscures the essence of your present question. `if (x) { y = a }` - are possible at all `y = a` execute before check `x`

Comment: So I Will ask another question in a different post. Thanks for your answer. I will delete the edit

Answer (score 3):

The memory barriers prevent the CPU from reordering accesses to the `Element` object, which are not using interlocks, across access to the queue structure (here implemented using indexes, but pointers are equally viable).

Using your numbering, it is essential that (3) is performed between (2) and (4), and a memory barrier provides that.

The exact case you ask about of (2)-vs-(3) in the Producer prevents speculatively overwriting valid data when the queue is full (the proposed site overlaps with valid data).  Without the barrier, even though when the condition failed the original data would be restored from the perspective of the Producer thread, intermediate values might be briefly visible to the Consumer.

Comment: *The exact case you ask about of (2)-vs-(3) in the Producer prevents speculatively overwriting valid data when the queue is full.*
So you mean that the producer could speculatively perform a store before executing the condition, and in case of test failure restoring the original one?

For the condition ( if(next_tail != _head.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) ), there is still a chance that the cpu first execute the load + the barrier *then* check the condition so the (3) operation could still be reordered between barrier and the condition, whar we are trying to avoid. Where am i wrong ?

Comment: @Yoo: You're not wrong, but since the condition won't stall the pipeline, there's zero advantage to performing speculation.  In contrast, waiting for a memory fetch can easily stall, so out-of-order execution makes sense.  Having zero payoff doesn't equate to formally forbidding speculation, to be theoretically correct I think the memory barrier should be inside the brace of the `if`, not in the controlling expression.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers !

Comment: I feel like this answer addresses more directly the original question, and should be the accepted answer.